# Ms Access VBA: How do I run a Sub Procedure that is stored in one DB on another DB?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a DB (we'll call it DB1) with a VBA procedure that loops through all sub folders in a file path and looks for other DB files with a certain string in the file path.  When it finds a DB with that string (we'll call it DB2), I need to run a Sub Procedure (that is stored in DB1) on DB2.  I have the code down to the point where it Opens DB2, but I can't figure out how to run the macro from DB1 on it.  I tried the appAccess.Run method first and then I tried the docmd.runmacro method but neither worked.

```
Sub RunExternalProcedure(strFilePath)
    Dim appAccess As Access.Application
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strFilePath, False
    'Run Sub procedure. 'appAccess.Run "TruncateTables"
    DoCmd.RunMacro "TruncateTables"
    Set appAccess = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Adapt your `TruncateTables` procedure so that it operates on the database which is identified by `strFilePath`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that (most likely) you are trying to run a procedure that isnt there. If i were you I would either:

1. Learn to check for existence of an object and on "not found" use the DoCmd.TransferDatabase command to move the module and then execute it.

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferdatabase
2. Make the file with the module you want to run a reference in the references. Then the access file without it can call it remotely.

   [Access 2010: linked database, reference, or add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060726/access-2010-linked-database-reference-or-add-in)

I would probably do #2, because then thats get you into a mindset of having a utility function DB that other access applications use for commonly used things (instead of copy/pasting the same funciton/sub everywhere).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Doug.  I had never heard of this method until now, sounds like something that could be extremely helpful for the work I do.  I couldn't find clear guidance on the simplest way to use a .accdb file as a reference in another DB (and also to do so programmatically for multiple files).  There is a lot of info there but also a lot of links/wormholes that get off the topic.  Any further guidance would be much appreciated.  Thanks again Doug!

Comment: @Chuck0185 See edited answer. It really is this simple.

Comment: Hey Doug, so I do know how to add references manually.  The issue is that I have hundreds of files that I need to run this procedure  on.  So I would need to add the reference through the VBA itself.  Is that possible?

Comment: @Chuck0185 Yes, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically